# AWS IAM policy issue for DynamoDB table access by authenticated Cognito users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm having a problem accessing a new DynamoDB table via a successfully authenticated Cognito user.

I get the following AccessDeniedException when attempting a scan of the table (using the AWS JavaScript SDK):

```
Unable to scan. Error: {
  "message": "User: arn:aws:sts::MY-ACCOUNT-NUM:assumed-role/Cognito_VODStreamTestAuth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials 
is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:MY-ACCOUNT-NUM:table/VideoCatalog",
  "code": "AccessDeniedException",
  "time": "2019-01-27T02:25:27.686Z",
  "requestId": "blahblah",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 18.559011800834146
}
```

The authenticated Cognito user policy has been extended with the following DynamoDB section:

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowedCatalogActions",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
     "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
     "dynamodb:GetItem",
     "dynamodb:Scan",
     "dynamodb:Query",
     "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
  ],
  "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:MY-ACCOUNT-NUM:table/VideoCatalog"
  ]
}
```

Shouldn't this be sufficient to give my authenticated Cognito users access to any DynamoDB table I might create, as long as I specify the table resource as I do above? Or do I *also* need to add ["Fine-grained access control"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/dynamodb/fgac) under the table's 'Access control' tab?

I can say that I created the VideoCatalog DynamoDB table under my non-root Administrator IAM role (represented above by MY-ACCOUNT-NUM). Is that a problem? (Prior to trying to move to a DynamoDB table I was using a JSON file on S3 as the video catalog.)

IAM confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error message from AWS and the policy document that you provided, I can see that there are two different regions here.

AWS is saying that your user does not have access to aws:dynamodb:**us-east-1**:MY-ACCOUNT-NUM:table/VideoCatalog, whereas your policy document is providing access to aws:dynamodb:**us-east-2**:MY-ACCOUNT-NUM:table/VideoCatalog.

Are you perhaps provisioning your resources in two different regions by mistake?

Comment: Not by mistake, per se... but thanks for noticing that! That table is definitely in the us-east-2 region whereas the Cognito user pool is in us-east-1. Seeing as I'm not specifying the region when I attempt to progammatically (using the AWS JavaScript SDK) scan VideoCatalog table, it must be assuming it's in the same region. There is no reason why I can't put the DynamoDB table in the same region as my Cognito User Pool.. so I will do that and report back!

Comment: You are precisely right. It's so easy to miss the us-east-1 vs. -2 but now I know to think region problems first! Thanks!!